# PHP ARRAY_PUSH strips html tag

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string which i am trying to split and then add a span tag on every 2 words.

When I split the string and try to use `array_push` to create a new array, **my html tags disappears**.

Here is my function:

```
public function splitString(){

    $string = Sample sentence;
    $newHeader = array();

    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
    $num = 1;

    foreach($parts as $str){

        if($num % 2 == 0){
            array_push($newHeader, "<span>".$str."</span>");
        }else{
            array_push($newHeader, $str);
        }

        $num++;
    }

    return $newHeader;
}
```

When I call that function the result i get is

```
Array ( [0] => Sample [1] => sentence )
```

I am looking for:

```
Array ( [0] => Sample [1] => <span>sentence</span> )
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help

Thank you in advance

Comment: If `$string = Sample sentence;` is your actual code, use quotes `$string = "Sample sentence";` - It's a string and not two constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you haven't corrected, just like @Fred said in the comments, you should quote your strings in that function:

```
$string = 'Sample sentence';
```

Second, it works. `array_push()` **does not** strip your tags. You are just presented with a `print_r()` on the browser but its there along with the word.

```
Array ( [0] => Sample [1] => sentence )
```

If look at it in the **view source**. This is what it looks like:

```
print_r(splitString());

Array
(
    [0] => Sample
    [1] => <span>sentence</span>
)
```

You just don't see it visually on the browser but the tags are there.

If you try to add this up:

```
array_push($newHeader, "<span style='color: red;'>".$str."</span>");
```

You'll see the style. Try it :)

Comment: 4x upvotes (as of this comment) including my own; can't go wrong ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks man, actually the only problem here is that unquoted string :) what follows are just further explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, what I find strange is that OP states: *"when i call that function the result i get is

`Array ( [0] => Sample [1] => sentence )`"* - OP may not be showing us everything, and/or error reporting isn't set/on. *Baffled*

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually when i think about it, i think its already quoted. lol :D since it already got into the `print_r()` dump

Comment: I've tested it to a certain degree, and by not quoting the string, got a parse error. OP may have just done a bad paste. But you know me, I take posted code literally ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- well i understand sometimes i do too haha. we haven't heard from the OP yet but i think the function invocation is the only missing piece on the question which isn't really important as the OP already shown the final result thru `print_r()`.

Comment: Grrrr. Thank you guys. Viewing the source never came up to me. Grr i feel soo stupid grrrr

Comment: I was trying to add HTML tags to my array using array_push and I couldn't see tags when I print the array but when I looked 'View Source' they were there. Thank you